# Spring MVC Spring Security and Error Handling

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

I'm using **ResponseEntityExceptionHandler** for global handling the error and almost working normal, except I want to handle wrong request with spring. By any logic overriding **handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod** should handle this, but insted of handling always get

> ## HTTP Status 404 -
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message**
>
> **description** The requested resource is not
>   available.
>
> #### Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.37

I just got this when enable debuging in console:

**WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI**

just to clarify by handling I mean I'm returning JSON.

any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason is [right there](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L1119), in the `DispatcherServlet` class; it sends error response without bothering to call exception handler (by default).

Since 4.0.0.RELEASE this behaviour can be simply changed with [throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L423) parameter:

> Set whether to throw a NoHandlerFoundException when no Handler was found for this request. This exception can then be caught with a HandlerExceptionResolver or an `@ExceptionHandler` controller method.

XML configuration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Java-based configuration:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
    }
    ...
}
```

Then `NoHandlerFoundException` can be handled like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    ResponseEntity handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        // return whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember to disable (or never enable) ``configureDefaultServletHandling`` in whatever class you have that ``extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`` or an exception will never be thrown for unmapped URLs, and hence can never be caught by this method. Technically I suppose all URLs are effectively mapped by /** if you do enable this setting.

Comment: Can someone give me some clue / hint on why "Java-based configuration" is working by not "XML configuration"

Answer (score 2):

`throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` take into account only if [no handlers for request found](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L911).

In case of `default-servlet-handler` was configured, `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler` will handle request. So, if this solution doesn't work, remove it and have a look (debug) this place of `DispatcherServlet`.