# Setting throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound has no effect in Spring 4.2.*

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, handlerexceptionresolver

Setting `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` has no effect in Spring 4.2.2. It is important for me since I have to send all responses as JSON.

I'm setting `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` in my *AppInitializer* like that:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    [...]

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
        boolean done = registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true"); // -> true
        if(!done) throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

It seems to work because [DispatcherServlet#noHandlerFound](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.2.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L1134) throwing Exception like expected:

```
// https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.2.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L1013
protected void noHandlerFound(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    if (pageNotFoundLogger.isWarnEnabled()) {
        pageNotFoundLogger.warn("No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [" + getRequestUri(request) +
                "] in DispatcherServlet with name '" + getServletName() + "'");
    }
    if (this.throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound) {
        throw new NoHandlerFoundException(request.getMethod(), getRequestUri(request),
                new ServletServerHttpRequest(request).getHeaders());
    }
    else {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

But then (it is very confusing!) EVERY exception [get catched](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.2.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L969) and [resolved to an error view](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.2.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L1013). So it is not possible to handle the `NoHandlerFoundException` by using Spring-`@ExceptionHandler`

**Question:**

I'm sure, it is very nice and useful feature, but is it any way to detect an 404 error to send a custom response instead of default html error page?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you manage to do it somehow?

Comment: @rpvilao, I have the same issue also, did you all solve it?

Comment: Don't remember exactly but I answered this question already below. I probably found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504905/handle-error-404-in-web-application-not-rest-application

Comment: same issue here, did you solved it ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to happen when we override to use the default servlet handling.
[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504905/handle-error-404-in-web-application-not-rest-application)