# Spring boot HandlerInterceptor loadbalancing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm implementing a (sort of) load balancing `HandlerInterceptor` using Spring Boot.

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    if (shouldUseServer1(uri)) {
        response.sendRedirect(server1Uri);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(server2Uri);
    }
}
```

The idea is, that based on the url, we either redirect to one service or another. The application doesn't have any explicit `RequestMapping`s (yet).

Now the problem is, when the interceptor is called, the request is redirected to the default Spring error handler. As a result the URI stored in the `HttpServletRequest` is replaced by `/error` (effectively denying the access to the original URI).

Is there any way to intercept a request before it is rerouted to the error handler (or to get the original uri)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Because of the way Spring MVC handles requests with no mapping, you'll either need a filter:

```
@Component
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        request.getSession().setAttribute("ORIGINAL_REQUEST_URI", request.getRequestURI());
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        // alternatively, ignore the last 2 lines
        // and just do your redirects from here 
        // and don't continue the filter chain
    }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {}

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

}
```

Otherwise, if you'd rather not rely on the session, [you'll need to make the `DispatcherServlet` throw an exception in case no handler mapping is found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22751886/4657798), and then send the redirect from a `@ControllerAdvice` error handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class NoHandlerFoundExceptionExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(value = NoHandlerFoundException.class)
  public ModelAndView
  defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, NoHandlerFoundException e) throws Exception {
    String uri = // resolve the URI
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + uri);
  }
}
```

To avoid duplication, you may want to have a common class that you'll call from both the interceptor and the error handler.

Comment: The redirect works fine. The problem is that I need the original URI from the request. In case there is no `RequestMapping` for the original URI, Spring will automatically redirect(?) to the default error controller. This redirection also changes the URI in the `HttpServletRequest` to `/error` (or some such). As a result, I can no longer access the original URI (to determine where I need to redirect to). My current workaround is to have a simple controller with a `RequestMapping(path = "**")`, but that seems like a dirty hack.

Comment: Ah, sorry, from your description I understood that the redirection to `/error` is happening in spite of the interceptor's redirect. I'll update my answer then, I think you should be okay with having a `Filter` that just saves the original request URI as a request attribute.

Comment: There, hope that helps. Your way of using a controller definitely requires less work and if I may be frank, probably is less of a hack :) Also, if you're just doing redirection, you're probably better off with a `Filter` implementation instead of using an interceptor/controller approach.

Comment: It did help. Thanks a bunch for the effort :)

Comment: Don't mention it, I learned a few things along the way, too :)