# How to handle 404 error in spring MVC using Controller Advice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i want to redirect all 404 errors to a error page, i have created a controllerAdvice but my method does not catch 404 error, i am using spring 3.3 throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound to true does not work

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod(final NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex)
    {
        final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(ERRORJSP);

        return mav;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle error 404 with Spring controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356549/handle-error-404-with-spring-controller)

Answer (score -1):

The evergreen `<error-page>` in web.xml could do the job.