# Spring MVC how are exceptions handled when no request mapping?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, error-handling, exception

What happens when all of the request mappings in the controller do not match the incoming request? I was using the exceptionhandler catching Exception.class but that did not seem to catch it? Can anyone explain?

Comment: If you have two mappings one for root `/` and another for say `/api` it will do closest match. Only api will get handled by /api but / and others will match the root I believe. Then you can handle whatever you like it /. Have you tried ?

Comment: Yes, currently it is doing a GET request but because there are no mappings  for that, (all are POST request mappings) I was wondering how I can catch the error/exception (whatever leads it to a HTTP 400 page) and not do a request mapping for a GET

Comment: If i correctly understand you. If comes a request that is not mapped result will be a page with 404 status code. Maybe you don't implements correctly your handler. If your project contains web.xml you may configure this using `<error-page>` tag ; In case it is based on annotation configuration view related post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356549/handle-error-404-with-spring-controller and if you are using spring boot define bean `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` and there configure Error page, that you will handle in controller.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-exceptionhandlers-resolver) `@ExceptionHandler` deal with unexpected exceptions that occur during controller execution. In the case when incoming request do not match any request mapping, controller method even will not be executed.

Spring-MVC based on Servlet technology. All incoming requests will be processed by `DispatcherServlet` (that registered in `web.xml`). `DispatcherServlet` looks for handlers which can process current request. If no appropriate handler will be found (i.e. no appropriate mapped controller's method will be found), `DispatcherServlet` initiates 404 error. 
When an error occurs, the web container(Tomcat or any other servlet container) generates a default page containing exception message. But you can also specify that the container should return a specific error page for a given exception. For process this error manually you should add into `web.xml` new `error-page` element, that will allow you map error code to url:

```
...

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/page-not-found</location>
</error-page>

...
```

Because `location` will be processed by Spring-MVC as usual request you can create controller to handle this request:

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionController{

    @RequestMapping("/page-not-found")
    public ModelAndView pageNotFound(){
        return new ModelAndView("page-not-found");
    }

}
```

Now just create view with name `page-not-found.jsp` and show exception info as you wish.